# Group a dataframe and count amount of items of a column that is not shown

Tags: python, pandas

Ok, I admit, I had troubles to really formulate a good header for that. So I will try to make give an example.

This is my sample dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
(1,"a","good"),
(1,"a","good"),
(1,"b","good"),
(1,"c","bad"),
(2,"a","good"),
(2,"b","bad"),
(3,"a","none")], columns=["id", "type", "eval"])
```

What I do with it is the following:

```
df.groupby(["id", "type"])["id"].agg({'id':'count'})
```

This results in:

```
        id
id type
1  a     2
   b     1
   c     1
2  a     1
   b     1
3  a     1
```

This is fine, although what I will need later on is that e.g. the id would be repeated in every row. But this is not the most important part.

What I would need now is something like this:

```
        id good bad none
id type
1  a     2    2   0    0
   b     1    1   0    0
   c     1    0   1    0
2  a     1    1   0    0
   b     1    0   1    0
3  a     1    0   0    1
```

And even better would be a result like this, because I will need this back in a dataframe (and finally in an Excel sheet) with all fields populated. In reality, there will be many more columns I am grouping by. They would have to be completely populated as well.

```
        id good bad none
id type
1  a     2    2   0    0
1  b     1    1   0    0
1  c     1    0   1    0
2  a     1    1   0    0
2  b     1    0   1    0
3  a     1    0   0    1
```

Thank you for helping me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) (last column was added) or [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby(["id", "type", 'eval'])
        .size()
        .unstack(fill_value=0)
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df1)
         bad  good  none
id type                 
1  a       0     2     0
   b       0     1     0
   c       1     0     0
2  a       0     1     0
   b       1     0     0
3  a       0     0     1
```

---

```
df1 = df.groupby(["id", "type"])[ 'eval']
        .value_counts()
        .unstack(fill_value=0)
        .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print (df1)
         bad  good  none
id type                 
1  a       0     2     0
   b       0     1     0
   c       1     0     0
2  a       0     1     0
   b       1     0     0
3  a       0     0     1
```

But for write to excel get:

```
df1.to_excel('file.xlsx')
```

[image: pic]

So need [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) last.

```
df1.reset_index().to_excel('file.xlsx', index=False)
```

[image: pic1]

EDIT:

I forget for `id` column, but it is duplicate column name, so need `id1`:

```
df1.insert(0, 'id1', df1.sum(axis=1))
```

Comment: Wow, this answer is really impressive to me. So fast and answering everything that was important to me. Thanks a lot jezrael!

My next task will be to add another column with the sum of C and D plus a further column with the total of C to E. But I think, I will get this done by myself ;-)

Comment: Glad can help! Writing Multiindex to excel is a bit problematic, so rather add some pics. ;)

Comment: I forget for it, so add it to the bottom of answer. Need [`insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html), because need first column, but `reset_index` raise error, so need rename `id` to `id1`. Good luck!